# mysqli-affected_rows and buffering

Tags: mysqli

I've read about a dozen posts on the doings of affected_rows.  I'm here now with an affected_rows returning 1 sometimes and 0 other times.  I understand it reports on changes.  An update that updates nothing will return a 0.  Changes are made - I can see it in the database.  There are no errors.  All calls are tested.

I've tried a store_result() before an affected_rows access.  No help.

Somewhere I read that buffering affects it's behavior.  My question is,
can you 'flush' after an update?  How?  Here is some abbr. code:

```
 $conn = db_connect();
 $sth = $conn->prepare($mysql_update);
 $sth->bind_param("siii", $name, $age, $wt, $ht);         
 $sth->execute();
 $sth->store_result();
 $update_count = $sth->affected_rows;
```

php 5.6, mysql 10.1.10-MariaDB (the xampp suite)

Additional: I don't close before I ask how many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just confused num_rows, which is affected by unbuffered query, with affcted_rows, which is not (as there is nothing actually to buffer at all). The latter is always available, and thus if you are getting 0, then no changes were made.

Comment: Thanks.  Always confused and always thankful.  I couldn't figure it out.  I decided for a patch; a read back.